# ASP.Net Button and the onclick event don't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, onclick

I make a dynamic table with buttons in they cells, but when i click some button show me this error in console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: bttn_Click is not defined
    at HTMLUnknownElement.onclick (VM51 panel.aspx:1)
```

this is how i make the button in html and asp.net :

```
StringBuilder htmlStr = new StringBuilder();
htmlStr.Append("<asp:button onclick='bttn_Click' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs'  ID='Bttn_PDF'>PDF</asp:button>");
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = htmlStr.ToString() });
```

and the C#

```
protected void bttn_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
  Button btn = (Button)sender;
  string btnid = btn.CommandArgument;
  test.Text = btnid;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether it will work or not, but you are missing runat="server" which is mandatory for controls rendered on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) event actually expects a Javascript-specific event to be called and you are currently trying to call a server-side event instead. When defining such an event on an actual ASP.NET Button control, you instead want to use the `OnClientClick` event instead. But this doesn't really matter as you want to target a server-side event and not a client-side one.

**Build Your Button Server-side**

What you'll likely want to do is create an actual Button control, define a click event handler that points to your method, and then add that control to the page as opposed to building a string:

```
// Build your button with its specific properties
Button button = new Button();
button.ID = "Bttn_PDF";
button.CssClass = "btn btn-warning btn-xs";
// Wire up its click event
button.Click += bttn_Click;
// Add it to the form
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(button);
```